# cancel an existing image on click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

In the actual website, when clicking on an image from thumbnails, it opens a slideshow.

I have created a new `onclick` event:

```
$('.thumbnails a').click(function(event) {

    //my piece of code

});
```

How can I cancel the existing on click event, not knowing which selector's been used to trigger the event (parent? child? specific class?)

I have tried things like:

```
event.stopPropagation()

$(this).stop()
```

with no success.

RE-EDIT--------------------------------------------------------

html starts with:

```
   <div class="images">


    <a title="Voyage itinérant en Boutre" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]" class="zoom" href="http://dev.snorkeling-voyages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/snorkeling-madagascar-001_alefa.jpg" itemprop="image">
    <img width="462" height="392" class="yit-image attachment-shop_single" src="http://dev.snorkeling-voyages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/snorkeling-madagascar-001_alefa-462x392.jpg">
    </a>
    
    
    <div class="thumbnails nomagnifier">

    <a class="zoom first" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]" title="bateau itinerant madagascar" href="http://dev.snorkeling-voyages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/snorkeling-madagascar-002_alefa.jpg">
    <img width="100" height="80" class="yit-image attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://dev.snorkeling-voyages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/snorkeling-madagascar-002_alefa-100x80.jpg"></a>
```

jQuery to change the featured image on thumbnails click:

```
  $('.thumbnails a').click(function(event) {

    var destination= $('.images >a');
    destination.empty();
    $(this).prependTo(".images >a");
    
    $('.images a a img').attr('width','470');
    $('.images a a img').attr('height','392');      
    //replace src string
    var src=($('.images img').attr('src'));     
     var pattern = /[100x80]/;
     if(pattern.test(src))
            src=src.replace("100x80", "462x392");
 
     $('.images a a img').attr('src',src);           
     $('.images a a img').attr('class','yit-image attachment-shop_single');
    
});
```

@bfavaretto comment helped me localise an existing a `.zoom` click event (very useful thanks)
(how can I know the js file? )

I have added a

```
     $('.zoom a').click(function(event) {
    return false ;
           // or  event.preventDefault();
});
```

and this does not prevent the slider from being opened still!

Comment: Do you want the slideshow *not* to open?

Comment: how about `event.preventDefault();` - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ  i have also tried event.preventDefault();

Comment: perhaps if you provided more code we can ascertain why `e.preventDefault()` doesnt work. do you have an associated `click` event for just `.thumbnails`? because then you would need `return false` instead, which encompasses both propagation and default event

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I think this is not about preventing the default, but about a separate slideshow script adding a separate event handler to the anchors.

Comment: if you have multiple scripts (plugins) placing different click handlers, that is an entirely separate issue. that issue, of course, is that u have no idea what your code is actually doing. i sincerely hope that isnt the case.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea that is the question ! how to cancel an on click event and override it, no matter knowing how it is triggered using which selector in which js file among 44 of them

Comment: Open the Chrome Developer Tools in the Sources tab. In the right pane, check "Event listener breakpoints > Mouse > click", then click your link. It will show you every piece of code being triggered by that click.

Comment: Your question is not descriptive enough!

Comment: i have added more info

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)** to prevent the link from executing:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERMtg/1)

Comment: It should work (see my fiddle). Maybe there is some else wrong in your code (eg. incorrect selector)? *Also: make sure your slideshow plugin does **not** change the DOM of your page. That would make your selector invalid.*

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all other click handlers from an element with `.off`:

```
$('.thumbnails a').off('click');
```

In case the event was delegated, you need something like this:

```
$(document).off('click', '.thumbnails a');
```

However, you have to do that from outside your click handler, or it may be too late.

Comment: i have put this at the beginning of the jquery file. none of the 2 does work

Comment: Maybe your code is running before the slideshow is binding its events? Or maybe you're using the wrong selectors (in the second case, if the event is not bound to `document`, it won't work). You have to know how the slideshow code binds the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using either of the two commented statements:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
//e.preventDefault();

//return false;
});
```

Comment: @Matoeil if you want the slideshow not to open then on the click you need to check if the slideshow exists in the DOM, you need to destroy the slideshow or completely remove it.

Comment: @Matoeil What do you want to do with your slideshow? Close, Remove or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I did something else If I understand correclty what you want please take a look

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">off</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">off</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">off</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">off</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('data-status') == 'on') {
        $(this).attr('data-status','off');
        $(this).html('off');
        return;
    }

    var areOn = 0;
    $('a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-status') == 'on') {
            areOn++;
        }
    })

    if (areOn == 0) { 
        $(this).attr('data-status','on');
        $(this).html('on');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ERMtg/9/

Comment: [I've made a little bit shorter way of your example. Have a look if you want to.](http://jsfiddle.net/ERMtg/10)

Comment: I really liked that :) @PetrR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return false`, I think that will do

```
$('.thumbnails a').click(function(event) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not really good practice as `return false;` also prevents that event from propagating.